# I cant get exist data from MySql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select data from 2 tables; First one is "Dictionary" and the second is "term_dic". The Problem is when the query is executed it's returning a repeated data or data not related with the query.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * from dictionary,term_dic where dictionary.task_ID = ? and term_dic.task_ID = ? ");

    //execute The Statment
    $stmt->execute(array($task,$task));
    // Assign To Variable

    $rows=$stmt->fetchAll();
        ?>


          <h1 class="text-center"><?php echo $_SESSION['TaskName']; ?></h1>
                 <div class="container">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class ="main-table text-center table table-bordered">
                           <tr>
                               <td>#ID</td>
                               <td>Word</td>
                               <td>From</td>
                               <td>To</td>
                               <td>Face EXP</td>
                               <td>Registerd Date</td>
                               <td>Control</td>
                           </tr>
                        <?php 

                                foreach ($rows as $row) {
                                    echo"<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['dic_ID'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['word'] . "</td>"; 
                                    echo "<td>".$row['start_from'] . "</td>"    ;
                                    echo "<td>".$row['end_to'] . "</td>"    ;
                                    echo "<td>".$row['face_exp'] . "</td>"  ;
                                    echo "<td>".$row['date_reg'] ."</td>";
                                     echo "<td><a href='dictionary.php?do=Edit&userid=". $row['dic_ID'] ."' class='btn btn-success'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Edit</a>
                                        <a href='dictionary.php?do=Delete&userid=". $row['dic_ID'] ."' class='btn btn-danger confirm'><i class='fa fa-close'></i> Delete </a>";







                                               echo "</td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                }

                         ?>
```

Comment: `($task,$task)` using the same variable here could be a conflict.

Comment: both tables are related to eachother?

Comment: Could you please `$stmt->execute(array($task,$task));` the `$task` values? what was inside the `array()`?

Comment: I have a task table that have task_ID , these 3 tables related with each other. for example i want just to get all information when dictionary.task_ID = 48 and term_dic = 48

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have addition Task table that's have task_ID and this task_ID were in dictionary and term_dic tables. So i want to get from dictionary and term_dic when they task_ID equals to $task